# Obtain ID token from Keycloak on Ruby on Rails with Omniauth to implement logout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, keycloak, omniauth, logout

I've been struggling to implement logout to my Ruby on Rails app. I'm running Keycloak v19.0.2 locally on port 8081. Therefore the logout url for realm `test-realm` is http://localhost:8081/realms/test-realm/protocol/openid-connect/logout.

According to the documentation [here](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#logout). I should redirect user to this url and provide query parameters with it. However I want to implement the logout without the prompt and redirect user back to the app with `post_logout_redirect_uri`. To do that I need to provide `id_token_hint` parameter, but what is this token and how to get it? My Keycloak authentication does only return access token and refresh token, not id token. I have tried to use both on this parameter and it does not work. And what I have searched online, it seems ID token is different from access token.

I have implemented the authentication to my Rails app with [omniauth](https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth) and [omniauth-keycloak](https://github.com/ccrockett/omniauth-keycloak) gems. For example I define `keycloak_openid` provider following way

```rb
provider(:keycloak_openid,
         Secrets.keycloak_client_id,
         Secrets.keycloak_client_secret,
         name: "keycloak",
         client_options: {
             base_url: "", site: "http://localhost:8081", realm: "test-realm"
         })
```

And I have defined a callback in my routes that will be called correctly for me where I can get access token and refresh token.

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Okay it seems I was missing scope parameter from the authentication query to the token api. So when requesting the token I need to provide `scope=openid` paremeter to the Keycloak. This makes the Keycloak return ID token alongside with access and refresh tokens.

The key bit of information I got from [here](https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/authentication-and-authorization-flow/add-login-auth-code-flow#parameters). Then by reading the omniauth-keycloak source code. It depends on [omniauth-oauth2](https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth-oauth2) gem. After reading that source, I found out that you can provide scope parameter when initializing the provider. So the provided should be initialized like this

```rb
provider(:keycloak_openid,
         Secrets.keycloak_client_id,
         Secrets.keycloak_client_secret,
         name: "keycloak",
         scope: "openid",
         client_options: {
             base_url: "", site: "http://localhost:8081", realm: "test-realm"
         })
```

Now the the ID token is returned by the Keycloak and can be provided for the logout `id_token_hint` parameter. With this the user is able logout without the prompt.

Comment: Which Authentication flow you are using in Keycloak for this? and what is the login URL look like?